# KendoChart: click on legend item - prevent default kendo behavior

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

Default behavior of clicking on legend item hides/showes corresponding series on the chart. 
How to prevent this?

I try

```
$(...).kendoChart({
...
        legendItemClick: onLegendItemClick
...
});
```

1)

```
function onLegendItemClick(e){
    //my code...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

2)

```
function onLegendItemClick(e){
    //my code...
    return false;
}
```

both of it doesn`t help.

Answer (score 6):

I know this Answer is little late, but it could somebody else.

Please see my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinayak_nandi/gtP55/4/)

```
legendItemClick : function ( e ){
      //on clicking the Legend Item, we need to prevent the default behavior.
      e.preventDefault();
 },
```

that will give you an Idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<%= Html.Kendo().Chart()
       .Name("Chart")
       .Events(events => events.LegendItemClick("onLegendItemClick"))
       %>


         function onLegendItemClick(e) {
               kendoConsole.log(kendo.format("Legend item click :: {0}",
                   e.text));
           }
```

Comment: From the example, he's using straight kendo, not MVC extensions so the first part will probably not make sense...

Comment: @Martin thanks for notify this. yes i know it's just example.